# How to lock screen in Openbox with KDE5 screen locker

Tags: command-line, openbox, kde5

`qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver Lock` gives

> Service 'org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver' does not exist.

and `loginctl lock-session` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kscreenlocker_greet` works.

Comment: How about a little context here? For a 2.5k user, this answer is bad.

Answer (score 2):

It works but you have to install `kscreenlocker_greet`.

On my (Debian) system there isn't.

```
[Mon 15May2017]bpxroot@thinkdeb:~$ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kscreenlocker_greet
bash: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kscreenlocker_greet: No such file or directory
```

But I have `loginctl`, so ...

first get the session's number:

```
[Mon 15May2017]bpxroot@thinkdeb:~$ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kscreenlocker_greet
bash: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kscreenlocker_greet: No such file or directory
[Mon 15May2017]bpxroot@thinkdeb:~$ loginctl 
   SESSION        UID USER             SEAT             TTY             
         4       1000 bpxroot          seat0                            

1 sessions listed.
```

then lock the session:

```
loginctl lock-session 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but I needed exactly KDE screen locker. On my system `loginctl lock-session #` does nothing.